# Outliner Not Responding To Settings

Tags: objects

A few days ago, while doing a preview in Iray for Daz Studio, my system locked up and Daz crashed.

After the system came back alive, I noticed several problems with performance and etc. Windows had updated that morning, I believe, no more than the day before. Anyway, I was able to get everything working again after reinstalling my chipset driver and Nvidia driver, etc. That is, everything except Blender.

Symptoms: the interface when rotating around an object is very stodgy, as though I were running an underpowered machine. In object mode, selecting an object does indicate the selection in the Scene Collection, but the yellow outline does not appear in the viewport around the selected objects.  I've made sure that the overlays button is blue (not grayed out) and that "Outline Selected" is indeed checked. Also, the UV Editor window only displays vertices, not the connecting edges against the background. I'm sure there are other things, but I'll stop there and only say further that this set of symptoms is consistent across 2.8, 3.1 and 3.6.

What I've tried:
Checking that Blender sees my video card.  It does.
Uninstalling all Blender versions, even cleaning out the registry very tediously by hand.
Reinstalled Blender 3.1.  Nothing is changed.  All symptoms remain.

```
System Info:
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name MSI
System Manufacturer Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
System Model    Bravo 15 C7VE
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  158N.1
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 7535HS with Radeon Graphics, 3301 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends International, LLC. E158NAMS.108, 3/30/2023
SMBIOS Version  3.4
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Product   MS-158N
BaseBoard Version   REV:1.0
Platform Role   Mobile

Graphics Subsystem:
Name    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_28A1&SUBSYS_13DD1462&REV_A1\4&14430B0E&0&0009
Adapter Type    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU, NVIDIA compatible
Adapter Description NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU
Adapter RAM (1,048,576) bytes
Installed Drivers   C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmiig.inf_amd64_0630a6f4b7e3b54b\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmiig.inf_amd64_0630a6f4b7e3b54b\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmiig.inf_amd64_0630a6f4b7e3b54b\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmiig.inf_amd64_0630a6f4b7e3b54b\nvldumdx.dll
Driver Version  31.0.15.4629
```

Any help would be appreciated. So far as I can tell, all other programs are now operating normally. Where else should I look?

Comment: Although you seem to have the latest graphics driver installed, the display issues you are seeing are usually caused by driver problems so I'd suspect a problem with the Windows system itself especially as it seems to have started after a Windows update. Also make sure that you **don't** have Windows set to update third-party drivers as ones from MS will not be the very latest ones. Get them direct from the Nvidia web site. I'd suggest you also read [Best place to put bug reports](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports) and work from there.

Comment: Thank you John, I'm downloading the studio Nvidia driver as we speak rather than the game ready.

Comment: I've always used the Studio one with Blender but I'm still using Windows 10 here.

Comment: Problem solved.  It was indeed a graphics issue but NOT the Nvidia driver.  This is an MSI laptop as you can see from the system info.  I opened their "MSI Center" and found a setting called "GPU Switch".  It was set to MSHybrid Graphics Mode.  I changed that to "Discrete Graphics Mode", rebooted, and now my outliner is back the lag is gone, and my entire system runs like new!
Watch out for those damned MSI updates, I assume that was involved somehow.  This goes back to what John said I suppose, I'll check that now.